# How to map the response from a REST service call to an input field in the form?

Tags: orbeon

In my form, a button triggers am Action to call a REST service

`http://localhost:8080/inventory/search?nr=a-001`

which returns an XML fragment

```
<item>
  <nr>a-001</nr>
  <name>Sample Name: a-001</name>
</item>
```

In the **Actions Editor**:

What is the correct XPath expression in **Source XPath Expression** to map the content of `item/name` into the field given by **Destination Control**?

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself. In this case, the content of the field **Source XPath Expression** in the **Action Editor** is `/item/name`.

Make sure the REST service replies XML with content type `application/xml`. If nothing happens when you click on the button, check `orbeon.log` for errors.